# Receiving arguments issue in java

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and trying to develop a simple android app. I'm trying to send two values from different activities as arguments to a third one. The problem is that the method that I'm using those two values, isn't seeing the values that's been entered by the user. Thanks in advance.
The code in that activity is:

```
public class NewAcount extends Activity {

    private DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    TextView final_Amount;
    EditText price, amount_Entered;
    double userr_Entered_Amount, itemPricee, result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.transparent);
        // amount of money the user wants to spend daily
        amount_Entered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Amount);
        // item price
        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Price);

        final_Amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Account_Result);
        // set the text view value
        final_Amount.setText(twoDigits.format(getTotal()));

    }

    public double getItemPrice(double itemPrice) {
        this.itemPricee = itemPrice;
        System.out.println("the item price in the new account activity is "
                + itemPricee);

        return itemPricee;
    }

    public double getUserAmountEntered(double user_Entered_Amount) {

        this.userr_Entered_Amount = user_Entered_Amount;
        System.out.println("the user amount in the new account activity is "
                + userr_Entered_Amount);

        return userr_Entered_Amount;

    }

    public double getTotal() {
        // Here where the problem is. it's not seeing
        // userr_Entered_Amount and itemPricee
            // and returns result as zero

result=getUserAmountEntered(userr_Entered_Amount)-getItemPrice(itemPricee);

        System.out.println("the result is " + result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

FinanceAppActivity.java
I'm sending the amount entered doing:

```
    if (amount_Entered.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        // start your expenses app activity
        Intent openYourExpensesActivity = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.FINANCESQLLITE");
        startActivity(openYourExpensesActivity);
        double user_Entered_Amount=Double.parseDouble(amount_Entered.getText().toString());
        //send amount entered to new account activity           
        NewAcount na=new NewAcount();           
        na.getUserAmountEntered(user_Entered_Amount);
    }
```

YourExpenses.java
sending item price

```
    // to determine which button was clicked
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_Add:
        boolean didItWork = true;
        try {
            String itemName = item.getText().toString();
            itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());         
            Price entry = new Price(YourExpenses.this);
            entry.open();
            // passing both strings to create entry method
            entry.creatEntry(itemName, itemPrice);  
            entry.close();
            NewAcount na=new NewAcount();
            //send item price to new account activity
            na.getItemPrice(itemPrice);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //code here                 
        } finally {

            if (didItWork) {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Inserted successfully!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent openNewAccount = new Intent("android.intent.action.TRANSPARENT");
                startActivity(openNewAccount);

            }
        }
```

Comment: What values are you expecting to be populated? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The values should be entered by the user. And when the user enters the amount of money he/she wants to spend and the item price, I'm expecting the result to be (The amount of money - item price). But it returns the result as zero even though getItemPrice()and getUserAmountEntered() methods print the actual amount that entered by the user.

Comment: I don't see where you are calling those methods in this Activity. What you need to do is create a submit `Button` in your layout and bind an `OnClickHandler` to it. When your `OnClick` method is invoked, you can then read the values from your text fields. You cannot call methods from one Activity on another. Also, please use the `Log` class not `System.out.println`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I don't want to use Button. It's a transparent activity that would tell the user, Your new account is ----. My question is,Why when I'm using println in both getItemPrice()and getUserAmountEntered(), it's printing the correct values, but getTotal() is not able to see those two values?

Comment: Your getter methods are returning exactly what you pass them. Why on earth are you doing that?

Comment: I can see where you are calling `getTotal`, but have no idea where you are calling the other methods. Please post more code.

I have a feeling you're trying to use an `Activity` where a `Dialog` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to call the public functions? This isn't going to work because "typically" only one Activity has the foreground at a time. You can pass values with intents as extras, use a sharedpreference, of most extreme extend Application and use that to house all your data.